# Print functionality in Rally/CA aAgile central application

Tags: rally

We have to add "Print" functionality in a Rally application.
We found this (Rally.ui.plugin.print.Print) API in Rally SDK. However we really don't understand how to use this.
We really appreciate,can some body help us (Some sample application).

We referred below URLs, however no conclusion.

https://xehelp.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.Print

https://communities.ca.com/thread/241763719

https://alliancerally.org

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: What exactly are you trying to print?  There are various different ways of doing it depending on what components you have in your app...